# Problemas para añadir un elemento

Tags: javascript, jquery

Acabo de crear una función anónima para que me añada más acordeones, pero no sé por qué no se quiere desplegar. Y tampoco quiere eliminarse ni editar el texto.

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.titulo_hijo').on('click',function(){
        let titulo_hijo = $(this).next();
        titulo_hijo.slideToggle();
    });

    $('.eliminar').on('click', function(){
        let eliminar = $(this).parent().parent().parent();
        eliminar.remove();
    });

    $('.editar').on('click', function(e){
        let editar = $(this).parent().prev();
        editar.attr("contentEditable","true");
        editar.focus();
        e.stopPropagation();
    });

    $('p').on('click', function(e){
        e.stopPropagation();
    });

    $('#btn-crear').on('click', function(){
        $('.contenedor').append(
            '<div class="contenedor_item">'+
                '<div class="titulo_hijo"><p>Titulo editable</p><div class="iconos"><img src="https://img.icons8.com/material-sharp/20/000000/pencil.png" class="editar" alt="Editar" title="Editar"><img src="https://img.icons8.com/ios/20/000000/waste-filled.png" class="eliminar" alt="Eliminar" title="Eliminar"></div></div>'+
                '<div class="hijo">'+
                    '<div class="nieto"><p>Titulo editable</p><div class="iconos"><img src="https://img.icons8.com/material-sharp/20/000000/pencil.png" class="editar" alt="Editar" title="Editar"><img src="https://img.icons8.com/ios/20/000000/waste-filled.png" class="eliminar" alt="Eliminar" title="Eliminar"></div></div>'+
                    '<div class="nieto"><p>Titulo editable</p><div class="iconos"><img src="https://img.icons8.com/material-sharp/20/000000/pencil.png" class="editar" alt="Editar" title="Editar"><img src="https://img.icons8.com/ios/20/000000/waste-filled.png" class="eliminar" alt="Eliminar" title="Eliminar"></div></div>'+
                    '<div class="nieto"><p>Titulo editable</p><div class="iconos"><img src="https://img.icons8.com/material-sharp/20/000000/pencil.png" class="editar" alt="Editar" title="Editar"><img src="https://img.icons8.com/ios/20/000000/waste-filled.png" class="eliminar" alt="Eliminar" title="Eliminar"></div></div>'+
                '</div>'+
            '</div>'
        );
    });

});
```

```css
input[type="submit"]{
    margin: 15px;
    cursor: pointer;
}

/**/

body{
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}

*{
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

.contenedor_item{
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    width: 100%;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    font-family: 'Source Sans Pro', sans-serif;
    font-weight: 700;
    font-size: 20px;
    margin-top: 10px;
}

.titulo_hijo{
    width: 95%;
    height: 50px;
}

.titulo_hijo{
    background: tomato;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.hijo{
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    width: 95%;
    display: none;
}

.titulo_hijo, .nieto{
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: center;
    border-radius: 5px;
    cursor: pointer;
    padding: 0 15px;
    box-shadow: 0 2px 5px #757575;
}

.nieto{
    background: wheat;
    width: 100%;
    height: 50px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.iconos{
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}

.eliminar{
    margin-left: 10px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <title>Pregunta</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="index5.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="index5.css">

    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Source+Sans+Pro:400,700" rel="stylesheet">

</head>
<body>
    <input id="btn-crear" type="submit" value="Añadir elemento nuevo">
    <div class="contenedor">
        <div class="contenedor_item">
            <div class="titulo_hijo"><p>Titulo editable</p><div class="iconos"><img src="https://img.icons8.com/material-sharp/20/000000/pencil.png" class="editar" alt="Editar" title="Editar"><img src="https://img.icons8.com/ios/20/000000/waste-filled.png" class="eliminar" alt="Eliminar" title="Eliminar"></div></div>
            <div class="hijo">
                <div class="nieto"><p>Titulo editable</p><div class="iconos"><img src="https://img.icons8.com/material-sharp/20/000000/pencil.png" class="editar" alt="Editar" title="Editar"><img src="https://img.icons8.com/ios/20/000000/waste-filled.png" class="eliminar" alt="Eliminar" title="Eliminar"></div></div>
                <div class="nieto"><p>Titulo editable</p><div class="iconos"><img src="https://img.icons8.com/material-sharp/20/000000/pencil.png" class="editar" alt="Editar" title="Editar"><img src="https://img.icons8.com/ios/20/000000/waste-filled.png" class="eliminar" alt="Eliminar" title="Eliminar"></div></div>
                <div class="nieto"><p>Titulo editable</p><div class="iconos"><img src="https://img.icons8.com/material-sharp/20/000000/pencil.png" class="editar" alt="Editar" title="Editar"><img src="https://img.icons8.com/ios/20/000000/waste-filled.png" class="eliminar" alt="Eliminar" title="Eliminar"></div></div>
            </div>
        </div>
        
        <div class="contenedor_item">
            <div class="titulo_hijo"><p>Titulo editable</p><div class="iconos"><img src="https://img.icons8.com/material-sharp/20/000000/pencil.png" class="editar" alt="Editar" title="Editar"><img src="https://img.icons8.com/ios/20/000000/waste-filled.png" class="eliminar" alt="Eliminar" title="Eliminar"></div></div>
            <div class="hijo">
                <div class="nieto"><p>Titulo editable</p><div class="iconos"><img src="https://img.icons8.com/material-sharp/20/000000/pencil.png" class="editar" alt="Editar" title="Editar"><img src="https://img.icons8.com/ios/20/000000/waste-filled.png" class="eliminar" alt="Eliminar" title="Eliminar"></div></div>
                <div class="nieto"><p>Titulo editable</p><div class="iconos"><img src="https://img.icons8.com/material-sharp/20/000000/pencil.png" class="editar" alt="Editar" title="Editar"><img src="https://img.icons8.com/ios/20/000000/waste-filled.png" class="eliminar" alt="Eliminar" title="Eliminar"></div></div>
                <div class="nieto"><p>Titulo editable</p><div class="iconos"><img src="https://img.icons8.com/material-sharp/20/000000/pencil.png" class="editar" alt="Editar" title="Editar"><img src="https://img.icons8.com/ios/20/000000/waste-filled.png" class="eliminar" alt="Eliminar" title="Eliminar"></div></div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="contenedor_item">
            <div class="titulo_hijo"><p>Titulo editable</p><div class="iconos"><img src="https://img.icons8.com/material-sharp/20/000000/pencil.png" class="editar" alt="Editar" title="Editar"><img src="https://img.icons8.com/ios/20/000000/waste-filled.png" class="eliminar" alt="Eliminar" title="Eliminar"></div></div>
            <div class="hijo">
                <div class="nieto"><p>Titulo editable</p><div class="iconos"><img src="https://img.icons8.com/material-sharp/20/000000/pencil.png" class="editar" alt="Editar" title="Editar"><img src="https://img.icons8.com/ios/20/000000/waste-filled.png" class="eliminar" alt="Eliminar" title="Eliminar"></div></div>
                <div class="nieto"><p>Titulo editable</p><div class="iconos"><img src="https://img.icons8.com/material-sharp/20/000000/pencil.png" class="editar" alt="Editar" title="Editar"><img src="https://img.icons8.com/ios/20/000000/waste-filled.png" class="eliminar" alt="Eliminar" title="Eliminar"></div></div>
                <div class="nieto"><p>Titulo editable</p><div class="iconos"><img src="https://img.icons8.com/material-sharp/20/000000/pencil.png" class="editar" alt="Editar" title="Editar"><img src="https://img.icons8.com/ios/20/000000/waste-filled.png" class="eliminar" alt="Eliminar" title="Eliminar"></div></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hola! El problema es que creas contenidos dinámicos al momento (en vivo) con `append` entonces como el código ya esta ejecutado, esos nuevos elementos no existen (Por así decirlo) y el javascript no los reconoce, intenta con `$(document).on('click','.tu_clase',function(){});` y me dices

Comment: una pregunta más, cuando hago .on('click',function....) no estaría creando algo parecido como addEventListener('click', function)? Porque si es así, debería ejecutarse las veces que yo quiera ya que es un listener.

Comment: Si es un evento de escucha, pero no siempre esta listo para aplicar la funcionalidad, como son "objetos" creados en el momento, no hay manera de que el Listener entienda que se creo algo. Más sin en cambio cuando ocupas el selector `document` este entenderá que siempre lo va a llamar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si quieres añadir eventos a futuros elementos con jQuery, tienes que indicarle un selector como segundo parámetro a la función `on`.

```
$(document).on('click', '.titulo_hijo', function(){
        let titulo_hijo = $(this).next();
        titulo_hijo.slideToggle();
    });
```

El evento será añadido a futuros elementos que tengan la clase `titulo_hijo`. Y al usar $(document) nos aseguramos de tener un "padre" que siempre existe.

[Aqui](https://jsfiddle.net/jupvsx4k/) tienes modificado tu codigo de como debería quedar.

Comment: Gracias, justo le estaba preguntando eso a @cignius. Pensaba que on.('...') era igual al addEventListener. Pero con el segundo parametro que entendido que sí.

Comment: Sinceramente, habria maneras mejor de hacer las cosas, pero eso pasa siempre. Por ejemplo, es más recomendable que crees el contenedor usando nodos que por string. Incluso mejor seria tener un nodo creado y clonarlo, ya que asi puedes tener un nodo con el evento y todo lo necesario añadido. Pero la gracia de la programación es que cada uno lo hace diferente!

Comment: jejeje, si te refieres a que repito y repito código tranquilo, sé que son malas practicas, y gracias por mencionar el método clone(). :)